# cakephp save multiple data hasmany relation

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to save multiple data at once, but cannot save data.

I have model of Post and model of Comment.

Post has many comments.

```
$this->WhAreaAllocation->saveAll($tempArray, array('deep' => true));
```

`$tempArray` is as below :

```
array(
    'post' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'title' => 'title1',
            'content' => 'content1',
            'comment' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'comment'=>'1st comment for post 1'
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'comment'=>'2nd comment for post 1'
                )
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
        'title' => 'title2',
            'content' => 'content2',
            'comment' => array(
                (int) 0 => array(
                    'comment'=>'1st comment for post 2'
                ),
                (int) 1 => array(
                    'comment'=>'2nd comment for post 2'
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: whats the issue you are facing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Saving hasMany through data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data)**

I don't know that you are saving post comments using form and also i am not sure about that which version of **cakephp** you are using but my solution is for **cakephp2.x** .If you wanna save data using form then create your post form like this and for saving has many mentioned related model name in fields.For example here you want save related comment of post see the code below

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Post'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.title'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Post.content'); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('Comment.comment'); ?>
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
<?php echo  $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Using this form u will get the request data like this.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Post] => Array
        (
            [title] => It is a post title
            [content] => you post content
        )

        [Comment] => Array
        (
            [comment] => this is my post comment
        )


    )
)
```

or if you wanna save data with out using form then u have to create data like this and also see **[CakePhp Save hasmany](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-hasmany-through-data)**

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [Post] => Array
            (
                [title] => It is a post title
                [content] => you post content
            )

            [0] => Array
            (
                [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [comment] => this is my post comment1
                )
            )

           [1] => Array
            (
                [Comment] => Array
                (
                    [comment] => this is my post comment2
                )
            )



        )
    )
```